# Mutliple URL Segments to Index Function With CodeIgniter

Tags: codeigniter, url-routing, codeigniter-url, php

Please excuse me if this is an incredibly stupid question, as I'm new to CodeIgniter.

I have a controller for my verification system called Verify. I'd like to be able to use it something like `site.com/verify/123/abcd`, but I only want to use the index function, so both URL segments need to go to it.

I'm sure this can be done with URL routing somehow, but I can't figure out how to pass both URL segments into Verify's index function..

Answer (score 7):

Something like this in routes.php should do the job:

$route['verify/(:any)/(:any)'] = "verify/index/$1/$2";

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you can just pass any controller method in CodeIgniter multiple arguments without modifying routes or .htaccess unless I misunderstood the problem.

```
function index($arg_one, $arg_two)
{

}
```

$arg_one representing the 123 and $arg_two representing the abcd in your example URI.

Comment: This would still require the URL to be site.com/verify/index/123/abcd

Comment: True, but this does answer the OP's question the way that it's been worded.

Answer (score 0):

You will either need to edit the routes or write an htaccess rule, however i didn't understand why you want to limit to just the index function.

Answer (score 0):

If you didnt wanna use routes for some reason, then you could add this function to the controller in question.

```
public function _remap($method_in, $params = array()) {
    $method = 'process_'.$method_in;
    if (method_exists($this, $method)) {
        return call_user_func_array(array($this, $method), $params);
    }
    array_unshift($params, $method_in);
    $this->index($params);
}
```

Basically it does the same as default behavior in CI, except instead of sending a 404 on 'cant find method', it sends unfound method calls to the index.

You would need to alter your index function to take an array as the first argument.
OR if you know that you only ever want 2 arguments, you could change the last 2 lines to

```
$this->index($method_in, $params[0]);
```

Of course both solutions fail in someone uses an argument which is the same as a method in your controller.